# Unclear documentation: Sharing state between processes

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is a part in the Python documentation that is unclear to me:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

"As mentioned above, when doing concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as far as possible."

But I cannot find any description above 17.2.1.5 that describes why it is best to avoid using shared state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Shared state is like a global variable, but… more global.

Not only do you have to consider what parts of your code are reading and modifying the state, but also *which running copy* of your code is accessing it, and how. This gets even trickier when the state is *mutable*, i.e. can be changed.

To make sure one thread doesn't stomp on what another thread is doing you have to [coordinate access to the state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing#Coordinating_access_to_shared_resources). That could be done using [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), [message-passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)#Concurrency_and_distribution_orientation), [software transactional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory), etc.

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil.

Comment: I still don't understand it. From the documentation: "This is particularly true when using multiple processes.". Is that really true? If a process is forked then the parent has no access to the variable of the child, so is it a "shared state"? It confusing me.

Comment: @Jonny The comment is made in a section of the documentation were they introduce specific means to achieve shared state. `fork`ing alone doesn't provide shared state but using the tools provided by the library you can obtain shared state. And they are simply saying: know what you are doing when using these cause you could have unexpected surprises.

Comment: @Jonny, does Bakuriu's comment help?